# Which tensorflow batch norm code is used when input rank is 4?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I am using `slim.batch_norm` from [layers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py) and trying to understand the code flow in my use case. It looks to me like the logic that decides whether to use `_fused_batch_norm()` or the base class will only use the `_fused_batch_norm()` in my case if the input rank is 2. The code description sounds like it should also be used if rank is 4 and the function itself (_fused_batch_norm()) supports rank of 4, but the logic seems to prevent calling it. Below is a snippet of the code showing what I am referring to:

```
  # Only use _fused_batch_norm (1) if fused is set True or if it is
  # possible to use (currently it doesn't support batch weights,
  # renorm, and the case when rank is neither 2 nor 4),
  # and (2) if used with zero_debias_moving_mean, or an input shape of rank 2,
  # or non-default updates_collections (not implemented in
  # normalization_layers.BatchNormalization yet); otherwise use the fused
  # implementation in normalization_layers.BatchNormalization.
  inputs = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
  rank = inputs.get_shape().ndims
  feature_supported = batch_weights is None and not renorm and rank in [2, 4]
  possible_to_fuse = fused is None and feature_supported
  if (fused or possible_to_fuse) and (
      zero_debias_moving_mean or rank == 2 or
      updates_collections is not ops.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS):
      return _fused_batch_norm(...)
```

For my use case, I have the following parameters all at default settings:

```
batch_weights=None
fused=False
renorm=False
zero_debias_moving_mean=False
updates_collections=ops.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS
```

If my input is rank 4, it looks like the code will use the fused implementation in `normalization_layers.BatchNormalization` Is my understanding of the logic correct?

Is this the expected and proper behavior? I am wondering if the the condition `rank==2` should actually be `rank in [2,4]`? If the latter is correct, then this would be a potential bug. If the original is correct, then why have `rank in [2,4]` for determining `feature_supported` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's a bug. When `rank=4` and `fused=None` (or `True`), an optimized `_fused_batch_norm` can and should be used. This agrees with [`tf.nn.fused_batch_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/fused_batch_norm).

Looks like they mixed up the logic expression, which should trigger if `possible_to_fuse=True`, no matter what everything else is. Moreover, if `feature_supported=True and not fused=False`, `_fused_batch_norm` is eligible as well.

You should report it to [tensorflow issue tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).